# code running fine on computer and on pydroid 3 it doesnt

Tags: python, pydroid

so i have made a script that when my phone connects to my wifi network it automatically turn on my computer and i downloaded pydroid on another phone to run it non stop and it outputs :

```
ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
```

and the code is this that works perfectly on a computer:

```py
import subprocess
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet

IP_DEVICE = 'phonesip'

devices = {
    'my_pc': {'mac': 'mymacadress', 'ip_address': 'myipadress'}
}


def wake_device(device_name):
    if device_name in devices:
        mac, ip = devices[device_name].values()
        send_magic_packet(mac, ip_address=ip)
        print('Magic Packet Sent')
    else:
        print('Device Not Found')


proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", '-t', IP_DEVICE], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else:
        None

    try:
        connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[2].replace(':', '')
        if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
            print('Device connected!')
            wake_device('my_pc')
            # Do whatever you want when the device connects here...
            break
        else:
            print('Pinging device...')
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Looks like the `ping` command works differently on your phone. What is your OS on your PC?

Comment: on my computer i use windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try omitting the `-t` from `ping` when running the script on your phone.

`ping` works differently on your phone. On windows you have to add `-t` for it to ping nonstop, on other operating systems that is the default behaviour.

Comment: i removed the -t and its just pings without proceeding to the wake device it just pings the ip

Comment: I see, that's because the output format of the `ping` is also different. I think changing `...split()[2]` to `...split()[3]` should do the trick. If not, just print the `ping` and check what else you have to modify.